# Date Formatting with two dates

Tags: java, date

I am converting the input string to date. When i try to give two dates as inputs `Date of Birth` and `Date of Joining`, i don't get any satisfied result. Also help me with re-promt if the input is invalid. Thanks in advance.

```
public class EmployeeInfo {
int id;
static String name, DoBS, DoJS;
Date DoB, DoJ;

public void checkDate(String dt) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");

    Date date = null;

    try {
        date = sdf1.parse(dt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        try {
            date = sdf2.parse(dt);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            try {
                date = sdf3.parse(dt);
            } catch (ParseException e2) {
                String invalid="Invalid,Retry";
                System.out.println(invalid);
                // TODO: Whatever to do when it doesn't find a date
            }
        }
    }

        setDateOfBirth(date);
        setDateOfJoining(date);
}


void setDateOfBirth(Date DoB) {
    this.DoB = DoB;
}

void setDateOfJoining(Date DoJ) {
    this.DoJ = DoJ;
}



void print() {
    System.out.println("User ID: " + id);
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Date Of Birth: " + DoB);
    System.out.println("Date of Joining: " + DoJ);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
    name = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the Date Of Birth: ");
    DoBS = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the Date of Joining: ");
    DoJS = scanner.nextLine();

    EmployeeInfo e = new EmployeeInfo();

    e.checkDate(DoBS);
    e.checkDate(DoJS);
    e.print();

}
}
```

Comment: You don't need to `try` within a `try`

Comment: Inputs are name,date of birth and date of joining. I want to print these things back. Date validation is the thing..

Comment: Code would be way much "cooler" if you had use some method "tryParse" or something like that

Comment: @cricket_007 `try` within a `try` is used to check different date formats.

Comment: `setDateOfBirth(date);
        setDateOfJoining(date);` is probably the issue the dates are always the same because of that..

Comment: It seems like you overwrite both dates with last valid date parsed, Use return date statement instead of void to assign those values

Comment: @RC. Then how can i print those dates?

Comment: @PanBrambor what should i return with Date type? i am not such familiar with date formatting..

Comment: my hint: first create one method to convert a String to date, that is, receives a string and converts to a date trying all formats, or throws the ParseException if unable.Then just call this method for each input.

Comment: @Ajnas O
change public void checkDate(String dt) throws ParseException
to 
public Date checkDate(String dt) throws ParseException 
and add return date at the end of this method

Comment: @PanBrambor did so.. then where should i call that date to print the result?

Comment: @Ajnas O You could use DoBS = checkDate(scanner.nextLine()); to store the result, and given that checkDate() will return null on fail, you could use loop to verify if formatting ended in success and if null is returned prompt for another try

Comment: @PanBrambor Can you help me with the code. Still i get it wrong..

Comment: @Ajnas O which part do you get wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went and fixed it up for you, its a bit hacked together, but will work just fine
First of all, you should have EmployeeInfo as separate class
EmployeeInfo.java

```
public class EmployeeInfo {
    int id;
    static String name;
    Date DoB, DoJ;

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(final Date DoB) {
        this.DoB = DoB;
    }

    public void setDateOfJoining(final Date DoJ) {
        this.DoJ = DoJ;
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println("User ID: " + id);
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Date Of Birth: " + DoB);
        System.out.println("Date of Joining: " + DoJ);
    }
}
```

And then you should have your main class that runs and has all the logic
Main.java

```
public class Main {    
    public static Date checkDate(final String dt) throws ParseException {

        final SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");

        Date date = null;

        try {
            date = sdf1.parse(dt);
        } catch (final ParseException e) {
            try {
                date = sdf2.parse(dt);
            } catch (final ParseException e1) {
                try {
                    date = sdf3.parse(dt);
                } catch (final ParseException e2) {
                    final String invalid = "Invalid,Retry";
                    System.out.println(invalid);
                }
            }
        }
        return date;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final EmployeeInfo e = new EmployeeInfo();
        System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
        e.setName(scanner.nextLine());
        Date d = null;
        while (d == null) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Date Of Birth: ");
            d = checkDate(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        e.setDateOfBirth(d);
        d = null;
        while (d == null) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Date of Joining: ");
            d = checkDate(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        e.setDateOfJoining(d);

        e.print();

    }
}
```

Hope this gives you some insight of how it is done. I implore you to compare both source codes, your amd mine and try to understand what has been changed and try to find out why(on your own).

Comment: when i enter a valid date, exception happens.. why so?

Comment: just noticed, date formats make no sense. Updated code

Comment: i think thats not the error.. something in `d = checkDate(scanner.nextLine());` in main method.

Comment: @AjnasO  For mee it works just fine, see the output:  
Enter the name:  
karel  
Enter the Date Of Birth:  
10-10/1856  
Invalid,Retry  
Enter the Date Of Birth:  
10-10-1856  
Enter the Date of Joining:  
10/10/1845  
User ID: 0  
Name: karel  
Date Of Birth: Fri Oct 10 00:00:00 CET 1856  
Date of Joining: Fri Oct 10 00:00:00 CET 1845  

If you are having na error instead, provide stact trace

Comment: Enter the name: 
Ajnas
Enter the Date Of Birth: 
28/04-1996
Invalid,Retry
Enter the Date Of Birth: 
28/04/1996
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
 at Employee.Main1.checkDate(Main1.java:18)
 at Employee.Main1.main(Main1.java:45)     This is the error encounters. tried `printstacktrace();` still same..

Comment: Wrong date import, use java.util.Date instead

Comment: the answer is accepted... thank you... but could you help me to remove those `00:00:00 CET` from the output?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat works both ways, just use .format(Date) to get formatted date